# Парсинг информации с сайта

Tags: java, android

Решил написать приложение для 1 сайта, для парсинга информации решил использовать jsoup, но столкнулся с проблемой, что некоторая информация на сайте хранится в джава-скриптах, в итоге я получаю html страницу, в которой нету этой информации(пишет:javascript отключен), интересует вопрос, как решить эту проблему либо альтернативные варианты) с парсингом только начинаю работать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript нельзя получить, но можно попробовать получить результат его выполнения. Скорее всего, то что вы видите на странице в браузере, это результат какого-то get/post запроса, соотвественно вам необходимо отправить такой же запрос с такими же параметрами и вы получите свой результат. Используйте fiddler2 либо вкладку network (в chrome), для подробного изучения всех запросов которые отправляет ваша страница.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно создавать скрытый `WebView`, грузить в него нужную страницу, а дальше выполнять JS для сбора данных со страницы.

[Как получать результат выполнения функций JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077097/2506123)

[Как выполнить JS в WebView.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291128/2506123)